# Pass array of td values from a table to a function class then insert to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table

TABLE.PHP - Table is correctly displaying. I just posted important codes here.

```
$ipn="192.168.196.";
echo "<form method ='post' action='class_prdsbmt.php'>";
echo "<table border='5'>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<table name='' border='3'>";
for($a1=51;$a1<68;$a1++){
    for($a2=52;$a2<70;$a2++){
        echo "<tr>";               
        echo "<td><input type='hidden' value='".$ipn.$a1."' name='td_a[]' />$ipn$a1</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='hidden' value='".$ipn.$a2."' name='td_a[]' />$ipn$a2</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $a1+=2;
        $a2+=1;
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</td>";
}

echo "<td><input type='submit' value='PRINT' name='btnss' /></td>";
```

class_prdsbmt.php

```
include("class_prdtrans.php");
$pcs = $_POST['td_a'];

for ($i = 0; $i < ; $i++) { 
    $arr=$pcs[$i];
    $printval = new PrintVal($arr,"TESTING ONLY");
    $crud = new CRUD_process();
}

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['btnss'])){
    $isSuccess=0;
    $strCol = "pcip,pcname";
    $strVal = "'".$printval->getIp()."','". $printval-   >getPcname()."'";
    $isSuccess = $crud->saveRecord("machine",$strCol,$strVal);
}else{
    "NOT SAVED! GO BACK!!!";
}

?>
```

class_prdtrans.php

```
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USER','user');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_NAME','db');

class PrintVal{
    var $_ipmac;

    function __construct($ipmac,$namemac){
        $this->_ipmac = $ipmac;
    }

    function getIp(){
        return $this->_ipmac;
    }

}


//crud operation
class CRUD_process{
    var $con;

    function __construct(){
        $this->con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    }

    function saveRecord($record,$columns,$values){
        $result = false;

        switch($record){
        case "machine":
            $result = $this->con->query("INSERT INTO tbl (".$columns.") VALUES(".$values.");");
            break;
        default:
        }
        return $result;
    }

    function getRecord($record,$values){
        $result = false;
        $val = explode(",",$values);

        switch($record){
        case "machine":
            $result = $this->con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE pcip  =".$val[0]." AND pcname = ".$val[1].";");
            break;
        default:
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Try to echo the `INSERT` query and the output is wrong. First field(pcip) values are null. Below is the SQL output.

```
INSERT INTO tbl (pcip,pcname) VALUES('','TESTING ONLY');
```

Please help me to come-up for a better way or simplest way to insert all array values of 'td_a[]' from a table to be inserted into my database once I click the button.

Comment: So, do some basic debugging to find out why your variable that you are using in that place is empty … And also, go read up on SQL injection and what you need to do about it.

Comment: @Brian Tompsett - 汤莱恩 Ok will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in class_prdsbmt.php

```
for ($i = 0; $i < ; $i++) { 
    $arr=$pcs[$i];
    $printval = new PrintVal($arr,"TESTING ONLY");
    $crud = new CRUD_process();
}
```

$i < ????, also you created so many obj CRUD for nothing. move it to if(isset condition below

Comment: Ooppss. It should be $i < count($pcs) but still i cannot get the correct output that I want. Okay I will try the if(isset condition). Thanks.

Comment: Also, the other created obj is for retrieving data later on.

Comment: I got it. I put it inside the if condition. Here's what I did.



if(isset($_POST['btnsbmt'])){
  $isSuccess=0;
  $pcs = $_POST["td_a"];
  //column
  
        for($i=0; $i<count($pcs); $i++){
        $hosts = New Hosts($pcs[$i],"PHTESTXX");
        $crud = new CRUD_process();
  $strCol = "pcip,pcname";
  $strVal = "'".$hosts->getInputip()."','". $hosts->getInputnamepc()."'";
  // call crud process function to execute query using parameters
  $isSuccess = $crud->saveRecord("comp",$strCol,$strVal);
        }
 }

Thank you.